# Is there a legal definition of an "annual report"?

Tags: corporate-law

When a statute talks about an annual report of an organization, is there a way to know what that means?  Is there a dictionary definition of an annual report that you can point toward?  Or if the definition of an annual report is unspecified, can the report writer come in at the last minute and write "annual report" in crayon on a napkin and legally call that an annual report? (I'm being dramatic with that example, but in general...?)

Example:

The Director has the following duties/functions:

K. To prepare and submit to the commissioner an annual report of the office's operations, activities and goals;

http://legislature.maine.gov/legis/statutes/10/title10sec8003.html

Comment: Do you have an example of such a statute?

Comment: Just edited to add the example

Comment: In this case, it seems clear that the submission must actually report "the office's operations, activities and goals."

Comment: So can they write three short sentences and that be it? (1. Operations are x. 2. Activities are Y.  3. Goals are Z)

Comment: I suppose the commissioner might be able to impose more rigorous standards, but without those, it would seem that the three short sentences wouldsatisfy the statute.

Comment: I take it you're not confident enough to make that an official answer?

Comment: That's correct. I'm just working from the plain meaning of the statute.  That's why I use the word "seem" so much ;-).  I'll leave a formal answer to someone who actually knows something about this, assuming such a person comes along.